# Calculate time until a change occurred without reverse

Tags: r, propertychanged

I'm very novice in r or any coding language.
I conducted an experiment where I tested the effect of copper on irrigation dripper blockage. I had dripper types "copper" and "normal" and once a week I measured whether they are working (1) or not (0). All the drippers started working (1) and all of them were blocked (0) by the end of the experiment. I also suspect that some type of debris might block the drippers based on their proximity to the water source so the position (lateral, position) columns are important. A sample of the data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1660089600, 1660089600, 1660521600, 
1660521600, 1660780800, 1660780800, 1661385600, 1661385600, 1661904000, 
1661904000, 1662249600, 1662249600, 1662336000, 1662336000), tzone = 
"UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Lateral = structure(c(2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = 
"factor"), 
Position = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"), class = "factor"), `Distance (m)` = c(0.9, 1.8, 0.9, 
1.8, 0.9, 1.8, 0.9, 1.8, 0.9, 1.8, 0.9, 1.8, 0.9, 1.8), Type = 
structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = 
c("Copper", 
"Normal"), class = "factor"), Working = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), id = c(6L, 18L, 
6L, 18L, 6L, 18L, 6L, 18L, 6L, 18L, 6L, 18L, 6L, 18L)), row.names = 
c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to calculate how much time (in days) it took a specific dripper to become blocked (switch from 1 to 0) and remain blocked to the end of the experiment. If any dripper was blocked but the following measurement it worked again then ignore the first 0 (perhaps flag this dripper).
I figured that I need to multiply the working column by the time difference from the start for each dripper and if it equals zero keep the previous date value otherwise keep the current value. However I don't understand how to write it.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made up an example dataset because you didn't provide a reproducible example, and I'm using the {tidyverse} package and style of code.

I'm assuming you have multiple drippers, and each one has its own `id` variable, and I'm also assuming each dripper gets measured once a day, so you can calculate the time it worked by subtracting the last date it worked from the first date.

Essentially, you find the appearance of the first two consecutive days the dripper didn't work, discard all data from then on for that particular dripper, and compute the difference between the last and first dates the dripper worked:

```
library(tidyverse)

# dripper 'a' is the simple case, it works for 4 days and stops after;
# dripper 'b' works for 3 days, stops on day 4, and continues for another 2 after, then stops for good
drippers_example <- tibble(
  id = rep(c("a","b"), each = 10),
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-08-18"), by = 1, length.out = 20),
  working = c(rep(1,4),rep(0,6), c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0))
)

# here you compute when the drippers stopped working
drippers_processed <-
  drippers_example %>%
  group_by(id) %>%  # process each dripper separately
  mutate(
    nonworking_consecutive_days = 
      # TRUE when current day is non-working and previous day was non-working also
      working==0 & lag(as.integer(working), n = 1, default = 1)==0,
    # set to TRUE after first consecutive non-working days
    stopped_working = cumsum(nonworking_consecutive_days) > 0
    ) %>%
  ungroup

dripper_summary <-
  drippers_processed %>%
  group_by(id) %>%  # summarise each dripper separately
  filter(!stopped_working) %>%  # keep only entries before they stopped working
  summarise(
    # compute difference between the end date and the start date - that's how long it worked for
    days_worked = as.numeric(max(date)-min(date), units = "days"),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

If you check `dripper_summary` you should get the following, as expected from the example data:

```
> dripper_summary
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  id    days_worked
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 a               4
2 b               6
```

Comment: I added a reproducible example of the dataframe (didn't know the dput can do that). Also added an "id" column to identify each dripper. However, measurement times are random and are according o the date column. When I try to run your code on my data I get an error message:Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `nonworking_consecutive_days = Working == 0 & lag(Working, n = 1, default = 1) == 0`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: id = 6.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! Can't combine `default` <double> and `x` <factor<8fa51>>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I see - it's because `Working` is a factor - you can either convert it to integer using `as.integer` when processing the data, or you can change that line to `nonworking_consecutive_days = Working == 0 & lag(as.integer(Working), n = 1, default = 1) == 0`;
the problem is that I've given `dplyr::lag()` a `default = 1` argument, which fails because 1 is numeric, but the vector itself is factor, so it fails!

Comment: Ok, I changed "Working" to integer and added a dummy date at the end to have at least 2 consecutive dates of 0. The "dripper_processed" works well now although I can't quite follow your logic or syntax (perhaps I need more time to read). The "dripper_summary" part is not working I think because it calculates days as.numeric" and not as.date?

Comment: The dummy date is a good point, I hadn't considered the case where a dripper stops working and you only have a single measurement.
`dripper_summary` computes the number of days the dripper worked before stopping, as described; if you need to know the date it last worked, you can get that by including inside `summarise`, e.g. `date_last_worked = max(date)`

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you! 
Just a last question. Summarise seems to return only the group_by and results and omits all other columns. I know I can join the dataframes but is there a way to keep all or some of the other columns?

Comment: Got it. I used `Lateral     = unique (Lateral)` inside `summarise` for each factor variable

Comment: You can also use the other variables (e.g. Position, Lateral, etc) inside `group_by` - because they're constant for each `id`, summarise will just retain them alongside `id`.